# Adding Wordpress database data

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I embedded a form in a plugin for wordpress and I want to take the data from this form and add it to the database I created separately. First of all, I want to add data to the database as a step, then I will get the data from the form.When I run my mysql query in mysql, everything is ok, I even added some data and my data in the form of select * from $ table_name comes in $ wpdb, but I can not run my insert query I tried all the solutions on this site array functions and so on. My transactions are listed below.

```
+----+----------+---------+--------+---------+
| id | username | company | email  | phone   |
+----+----------+---------+--------+---------+
|  1 | aaaa     | aaaa    | aaaa   | aa      |
|  2 | aaaa     | aaaa    | aaaa   | aa      |
| 23 | asd      | 2313123 | sadasd | 1asdasd |
+----+----------+---------+--------+---------+
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| username | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| company  | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| email    | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| phone    | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

wordpress code

```
 require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-load.php');
   
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name= $wpdb->prefix . "eventuser";
 
    $sql="INSERT INTO $table_name ('id','username','company','email','phone') values ('54','adsadasd','easdasdasdmail','comadssadpany','eveadasdasdnt')";
    var_dump($wpdb->query($sql));
```

query example

```
insert into wp_eventuser (id,username,company,email,phone) values ("45","asd","2313123","sadasd","1asdasd");
```

Return code

> Query OK, 1 row affected (0.002 sec)

End return debug mode

```
echo $sql;
```

> bool(false) INSERT INTO wp_eventuser ('username','company','email','phone') values ('adsadasd','easdasdasdmail','comadssadpany','eveadasdasdnt')

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-load.php');

global $wpdb;
$table_name= $wpdb->prefix . "eventuser";

$sql="INSERT INTO $table_name (id,username,company,email,phone) values ('54','adsadasd','easdasdasdmail','comadssadpany','eveadasdasdnt')";
var_dump($wpdb->query($sql));
```

this problem fixed